# python typing: list with length

Tags: python, typing

I would like to use python's [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module to check and document function arguments and the like.

Let's say I wanted to require a list with two elements, both of which are `ints` (e.g. `[1,2]`, `[214,12]` are good while `[1,2,3]` or `[214., 12]` are bad). Is there a way to specify this? (Or is there, maybe, some deep reason why this wouldn't make sense for a python list?)

I see that you can do something like this with [`Typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple). However, the functionality seems somewhat limited.

Comment: Use your own validator function, check len(input) == 2 and each element in input are integers

Comment: What do you mean *"limited"*? You can definitely express what you describe here.

Comment: I think you mean ```214``` and not ```214.```

Comment: Typing and length-checks do not go hand in hand. Typing is used by some ide`s for compile time type checking/hinting. It is not enforced. Use a combination of typing ( `def do_something( data: List[int]) -> List[int]:` and normal length check assertions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the question. I was not able to find it previously. @Sid `214.` was an example of a bad case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you could answer the linked question that would be great. Both answers there point to the conclusion that this is not something that can or ought to be done.